# PHP conditional HTML not working

Tags: php, html, session

I'm struggling to get this PHP conditional statement to work, I have ensured that the session variable `ID` is not set by using `session_destroy()`, however no matter whether the `ID` variable is set or not the dropdown menu is displayed rather than the login button:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Catalogue</a></li>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['ID']) && $_SESSION['ID'] != ""): ?>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="profile.html">Overview</a>
                <a href="editdetails.html">Edit Details</a>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My desired outcome is that when the session variable `ID` is set, the dropdown menu is visible, otherwise the login button is visible.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `$_SESSION['ID']` contains, e.g. by using a debugger, `echo`ing it out, using `var_dump()`, or `print_r()`?

Comment: what is $_SESSION['ID'] at the time?  Sometimes you get things set that you didn't mean to set....  I would also use if(!empty($_SESSION['ID']) - does what I believe you are looking for here.

Comment: Hi, I've just `echo'd` it and its a sql selection statement, so I think what the issue is that where I've set it, I've made a mistake and set it as the selection statement rather than the selected value. However, that doesn't explain why it is still set when I've used `session_destroy()` multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.

`session_destroy()` doesn't destroy the session cookie and the globals related to the current session.

Try again using `session_unset()` to clear all the variables related.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know that! I'll give it a go :)

Comment: That worked like a charm, cheers - completely new to PHP so assumed `session_destroy()` just destroyed everything!

Comment: Excellent. Glad that it helped. :) Feel free to validate the answer.